# how to change the row of a DataFrame depending on values of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a huge dataframe with multiple time series like in the link below.

[Dataframe with multiple time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN6H1.png)

At the end there should be a dataframe with the same values like before except when there is no value (nan) in column g. Shortly said, if there is a value in column g all the other rows should stay the same. If there is a "nan" in column g, all the other values should be also "nan" in this row.There are up to 200 Columns in this dataframe so is it possible to write it in a way without writing the individual column names like in a lot of examples. I tried it with df.iloc and np.where but honestly said, I cannot define the conditions to make it work.

[Solution with rows adapted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeQtN.png)

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't post pics of the data/code. Post the actual data sample and code in the question.

Comment: thank you chitown88. you are right. I postet already the code I am using with the suggestion of an other user.Unfortunately it doesn't work. Your solution with np.where and isnull is pretty nice but the two rows without values in column 'g' did not change either to 'nan'. I played a little bit around and changed it to (df.columns)[:-1].
I still have to learn so much...

Comment: Oh ok, so are you saying ALL col;umns need to be nan? I was under the impression all the value columns (not including date) columns.

Comment: I updated the solution. Can I ask, what is the end goal? Why make all the values in the row nan?

Comment: I have to set Date as index so there won't be a nan in the date time series. But now it works perfectly.Thanks a lot chitown88. 
I work with stock price returns and in column 'g' are the benchmark values, which all the other values depend on. So if there is no data on this day there should also be no data in the other columns.I cannot replace nan with 0 or delete the row because it would make it impossible to calculate correct averages or other calculations.So I think that's the best way to use it.

Comment: Ah ok. Gotcha. Was just wondering because was curious if there was a better way. But I see what you mean. If you need the date/row for the correct calculation then ya, just turning all to nan makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['Date','a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
data = [
  ['01.06.2022','0,574','0,2342','0,574','0,2342','0,574','0,2342','0,574'],
  ['02.06.2022','0,574','0,2342','0,574','0,2342','0,574','0,2342',np.nan],
  ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

check_col = 'g'
rows_to_adapt = [x for x in df.columns if x != check_col]

for col in rows_to_adapt:
    df[col] = np.where(df['g'].isnull(), np.nan, df[col])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in df.index:
    if np.isnan(df.loc[index, "g"]):
        df.loc[index, :] = np.nan
```

This should work if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you r.uzunok! Unfortunately the output is the same.On 2022-01-02 and 2022-01-05 should all values in the two rows be replaced by 'nan'.
That's the code now.What do I overlook?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'price': [10, 11, 9, 13, 14, 18, 17, 19],
 'volume': [50, 60, 40, 100, 50, 100, 40, 50],
 'age': [14, 67, 91, 10, 54, 33, 28, 81],
 'g': [50, 'nan', 40, 100, 'nan', 100, 40, 50],
 'Date':["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07", "2022-01-08"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.set_index("Date")
for index in df.index:
if pd.isna(df.loc[index, "g"]):
    df.loc[index, :] = np.nan
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).